# Webpage error in ie8 asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, internet-explorer-8

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 23 Jan 2013 05:01:55 UTC


Message: Object expected
Line: 62
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:4001/abc.aspx?id=12
```

I am getting this error in every page and specifically in ie8 . My script that is causing the issue is

```
<script type="text/javascript">DM_redirect("http://mobile.dudamobile.com/site/abc");      </script>
```

It works perfectly on both Google Chrome and Mozilla

How do i get rid of this issue

**The Script being used is this**

```
http://static.dudamobile.com/DM_redirect.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue some weeks ago. You basically have to specify "javascript" in language because IE8 will read something else.

At last that worked for me.